# PHPUnit hanging on first test of third testcase class

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.1

Running Laravel 5.1

I've got a couple of testcase classes, each one runs fine by itself but when I run them together, eg. >phpunit without a filter, it hangs on the first test of the final testcase class. (I implemented my own listener so I could see which suites where running.

It doesn't break or just stop, it just sits at the command line and I have to ctrl C to stop the batch file.  If I remove the first test case in the 3rd suite, it hangs on the next test.

I put  in the xml file and also run it with --stderr, to no avail.

Comment: Follow up. I created a new test class to run before the problem class and that didn't help, but when I renamed the class that was hanging so it came first the application suite ran fine.

Comment: Follow up II.  It may be a db issue in my setUp().  I'm running a seeder.  This was why it made no difference which test came first.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?